# Discord javascript bot creation error "message not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

The script is following:

```
client.login(config.token);

var commandsList = fs.readFileSync('D:/DiscordBot/commands.txt', 'utf8');

   if(message === (command = 'help')) {
    message.channel.send(commandList);
    message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
}
```

The error log looks like that:

```
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DiscordBot\index.js:147:4)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

I cant solve this problem, please help!!

Comment: You do not have `message` variable declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**This post assumes you're running discord.js**

This should be a quick fix. Make sure that `command` is defined, and that you're using `==` or `===` to check for equality instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

Also, make sure that you're updating every time a message is sent!

You probably want to do something like this:

```js
const commandList = fs.readFileSync('D:/DiscordBot/commands.txt', 'utf8');

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("help")) {
        // do whatever with message
    }
});
```

Comment: should be `message.content.startsWith("help")`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is listen to when messages are sent. This is called an event. When a message is sent, an event is sent to the discord's API notifying that a message has been sent. To listen to the message event, you can use the code: `client.on("message", callback)`.

`callback` should basically be a function. E.g.

```js
client.on("message", function(message) {
     console.log(message.author); // this will log the person who sent the message
});
```

rather than that, I prefer using arrow functions:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
     console.log(message.author); // this will log the person who sent the message
});
```

or you can code the function separately and pass it as argument:

```js
// Or you declare this with arrow functions
function messageEventFunction(message) {
     console.log(message.author); // this will log the person who sent the message
}

client.on("message", messageEventFunction);
```

You can view a list of available functions @ https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

Think of it like there are two people talking in your backyard (an event) and you are eavesdropping on the 2 people (listening to the event) and about to decide what to do next (the rest of your code).